# How does this user have two reputation and no net positive reputation changes?

Tags: support, bug, reputation

On Puzzling.SE (in private beta), [this user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/157/daniel-que) has two reputation.

This occurred after I downvoted one of their answers, then later undownvoted it.

[image]

I've never seen this behavior before, and since reputation updates instantly, this can't be caching.

What happened here?

Comment: Reputation does not always update instantly. It takes up to 15 minutes for reputation to update after a deletion. (Not sure if a deletion is the cause, just straightening that out.)

Comment: @animuson It's been a while - no adjustments yet. They received one upvote, though, and are now at 12 reputation.

Comment: Wild guess: he downvoted an answer, and it was deleted?

Comment: Scratch that; I tried it on [a testing account](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/161/user161?tab=reputation) and it still has 1 rep.